# Comparison between dataframes without loops

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, optimization

I have 2 Data Frames structured like those:

Df1:

| gene ids | Go terms |
| --- | --- |
| ID1 | GO1 |
| ID1 | GO2 |
| ID2 | GO1 |
| ID2 | GO3 |
| ID3 | GO1 |
| ID4 | GO1 |

Df2:

| MP terms | MP names | gene ids |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MP1 | Name1 | ID1, ID2, ID4 |
| MP2 | Name2 | ID1,ID3 |
| MP3 | Name3 | ID2 |

Now I would like to create a third Data Frame combining the previous two in this way:

Df3:

| gene ids | Mp terms | GO terms |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | MP1,MP2 | GO1,GO2 |
| ID2 | MP1,MP3 | GO1,GO3 |
| ID3 | MP2 | GO1 |
| ID4 | MP1 | GO1 |

So in the first column there are the ids from Df1 (without repetitions), in the second column the mp from Df2 associated to the ids and in the third column the go terms from Df1 associated to the gene ids.
I would be able to do it with a for loop with nested loops but I know it would be a very inefficient approach. I would like to know how to do it avoiding loops.
Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) to join the rows with a common ID as string, and [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)+[`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) to expand to multiple rows. Finally [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) the two parts to align your output:

```
out = (
 df1.groupby('gene ids', as_index=False).agg(','.join)
    .merge((df2.assign(**{'gene ids': lambda d: d['gene ids'].str.split(r',\s*')}).explode('gene ids')
               .groupby('gene ids', as_index=False).agg(', '.join)
            ), how='left')
)
```

Output:

```
  gene ids Go terms  MP terms      MP names
0      ID1  GO1,GO2  MP1, MP2  Name1, Name2
1      ID2  GO1,GO3  MP1, MP3  Name1, Name3
2      ID3      GO1       MP2         Name2
3      ID4      GO1       MP1         Name1
```

If you're not interested in the "MP names" column, slice in the second `groupby.agg`:

```
out = (
 df1.groupby('gene ids', as_index=False).agg(','.join)
    .merge((df2.assign(**{'gene ids': lambda d: d['gene ids'].str.split(r',\s*')}).explode('gene ids')
               .groupby('gene ids', as_index=False)['MP terms'].agg(', '.join)
            ), how='left')
)
```

Output:

```
  gene ids Go terms  MP terms
0      ID1  GO1,GO2  MP1, MP2
1      ID2  GO1,GO3  MP1, MP3
2      ID3      GO1       MP2
3      ID4      GO1       MP1
```

Comment: Thank you very much, with the second command I have exactly the output I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with aggregation by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) and `join` with [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) splitted values by `,` in `df2`:

```
df = pd.concat([df2.assign(**{'gene ids': df2['gene ids'].str.split(',\s*')})
                   .explode('gene ids')
                   .groupby('gene ids')['MP terms'].agg(', '.join),
                df1.groupby('gene ids')['Go terms'].agg(', '.join)], axis=1).reset_index()
print (df)
  gene ids  MP terms  Go terms
0      ID1  MP1, MP2  GO1, GO2
1      ID2  MP1, MP3  GO1, GO3
2      ID3       MP2       GO1
3      ID4       MP1       GO1
```

If need aggregate all columns by `join` use:

```
df = pd.concat([df2.assign(**{'gene ids': df2['gene ids'].str.split(',\s*')})
                   .explode('gene ids')
                   .groupby('gene ids').agg(', '.join),
                df1.groupby('gene ids').agg(', '.join)], axis=1).reset_index()
print (df)
  gene ids  MP terms      MP names  Go terms
0      ID1  MP1, MP2  Name1, Name2  GO1, GO2
1      ID2  MP1, MP3  Name1, Name3  GO1, GO3
2      ID3       MP2         Name2       GO1
3      ID4       MP1         Name1       GO1
```